# How to call a method of a child class of a father class type list? C++

Tags: c++, list, parent-child

Ok so I have the situation set up:

```
ClassA() 
{
     method();
}
ClassB: public ClassA()
{
     overrides method();
}
```

The I have this situtation going on another class:

```
list<ClassA> members;
addMethod(ClassA newMember)
{
     members.push_back(newMember);
}

update()
{
   for(std::list<ClassA>::iterator list_iter = members.begin(); list_iter != members.end(); list_iter++)
   {
       ClassA tklb = *list_iter;
       tklb.method();
   }

    return 0;
 }
```

The thing is that when I'm doing tklb.method() I want to call the on from the child class but he always calls from the parent class since it's a list . I need this since I have other classes that are child of classA and will do 'method' differently.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pointers to the item for it to behave polymorphically.  You are at the moment in danger of [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) as an object could be placed in the list via a copy constructor.

In addition for a method to behave as you describe ([polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)) you are required to declare the method as `virtual`. (I assume the lack of return type is a typo?).

Change to a `std::list<ClassA*>` (or better yet an appropriate smart pointer).

Comment: You could also point out that `method` needs to be `virtual` (and have a return type)